Convert an OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code to a Token in a Python Tool Using Google Cloud Platform
I'm working on a .pyt Python geoprocessing tool that runs inside ArcGis Pro that needs to authenticate with Google Cloud Platform services using OAuth 2.0. I've managed to get the authorization code using the PKCE enhancement, but I'm stuck on exchanging this code for an access token. My environment does not allow for secure handling of the client secret, I'm trying to implement this flow without exposing the Client Secret.
I have tried using OAuth 2.0 Client Desktop and Web App IDs. And have double checked scopes.
Here's the part of the code where I generate the code verifier and challenge, and make the authorization request:
import hashlib
import base64
import os
import webbrowser
import requests

CLIENT_ID = 'your_client_id_here'
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8080'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

def generate_code_verifier():
    token = os.urandom(30)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(token).rstrip(b'=').decode('utf-8')

def generate_code_challenge(verifier):
    digest = hashlib.sha256(verifier.encode('utf-8')).digest()
    challenge = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(digest).rstrip(b'=').decode('utf-8')
    return challenge

verifier = generate_code_verifier()
challenge = generate_code_challenge(verifier)

AUTH_URL = f"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&scope={' '.join(SCOPES)}&code_challenge={challenge}&code_challenge_method=S256&access_type=offline&prompt=consent"

webbrowser.open_new(AUTH_URL)

After the user authorizes the application, I get an authorization code redirected to my local server. Now I need to exchange this authorization code for an access token. Here's my attempt:
def exchange_code_for_token(code):
    token_url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
    data = {
        'code': code,
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
        'code_verifier': verifier,  # Include the verifier in the token exchange request
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()  # This should contain the access token
    else:
        return response.text

# Assuming 'code' is the authorization code received from Google
token_data = exchange_code_for_token('your_authorization_code_here')
print(token_data)

When I run this, I get the following error:
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "client_secret is missing."
}

I understand that typically the client secret would be included here, but I'm trying to avoid exposing it, given my constraints. How can I properly exchange the authorization code for a token without using a client secret in this context? Is it possible to utilize PKCE here or another method to secure this exchange?
